# struct.unpack with precision after decimal points

Tags: python, struct

I am reading data from a binary file, it contains floating point data of which I want only first 6 digits after decimal point but its printing a pretty long string.

`self.dataArray.append(struct.unpack("f", buf)[0])`

I tried with this

`self.dataArray.append(struct.unpack(".6f", buf)[0])`

But it didn't worked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's a formatting issue, not an unpacking issue. You can't unpack half a float.

Comment: okk, was just dubious so wanted to check if it was possible.

Answer (score 4):

a float isnt a string and a string isnt a float.

all a float is, is a number of bytes interpreted as both a whole number part and a fractional part

```
the_float = struct.unpack("f", buf)[0]

print "The Float String %0.6f"%(the_float)
```